# RunOnUiThread inside loop efficiency

Tags: android

Is it fine to do following if we think about efficiency?

```
new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final Runnable uitask = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //sth that modifies UI
                    }
                };

                for (...) {
                    context.runOnUiThread(uitask);
                    Thread.sleep(...);
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm most concerned about that runOnUi might create new thread each time, which would be very bad? Am I right or it smarter like ThreadPool?

Comment: you can achive the same without `Thread.sleep(...)` and thread at all ...                final Handler handler = new Handler();
               final Runnable uitask;
               uitask = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //sth that modifies UI
                        handler.postDelayed(uitask, timeToWait);
                    }
                };
               handler.post(uitask);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, runOnUiThread doesn't create new threads, it is starting your runnable on the existing UI thread.

but instead of your code you could just do

```
 void onCreate(..) {
     ...
     mHandler = new Handler();
 }

 for (...) {
     mHandler.postDelayed(uitask, DELAY * i++);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm most concerned about that runOnUi might create new thread each
>   time, which would be very bad?

Well. It depends what you want to achieve. In Android, native threads are not much efficient. There are more effective ways how to do background work (SDK provides them).

If you want to do some periodical work you can use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to achieve your goal. Just create only one `Runnable` and then you can send request for periodical callbacks. Another solution is to use [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which run in background. They're directly designated for long-running tasks and provide very handy way for background processing.

Sometimes you need to inform user with some information about current progress in your tasks so in this case you can simply use mentioned Handler or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

I think your solution is not clean and efficient. If you'll create for example 40 Threads, your work won't be faster or more efficient at all. Your GB will scream and application will take the greater part of `CPU` and high battery consumption is something you shouldn't allow.